# Stop the decay of closing votes when a bounty is set

Tags: feature-request, closing, bounty

Some week or so ago I answered a question, after some comments with the OP it became my suspicion that the question was not made in good faith, but rather to "confirm that they are correct", rather than seeking an answer.

I deleted my answer and voted to close. If I recall correctly the question had two or three closing votes, and then the OP set a bounty on the question. Of course, now it is impossible to close the question until the bounty is awarded or expires.

The bounty was given yesterday, but now the closing votes have decayed and gone. So now instead of just two people, it is necessary that five people will take interest in closing this question, and the three previously agreeing to that, are no longer eligible for voting.

---

Is it possible to halt the process of aging on closing votes once a bounty is given?

Comment: Related: Is it intended that someone can prevent the closing of his question by placing a bounty on it?  Interesting strategy (if so)!

Comment: @GEdgar Well, I see the point of this design: loosing all rep invested in bounty because of question closure would be very frustrating. (But I dislike usage of bounties to evade closure very much.)

Comment: @Grigory: I can understand why a question with an open bounty shouldn't, in general, be closed down. It shows that the OP has invested more than just typing into the question; but if it turns out that the reasons to close the question are just as valid after the bounty expires as they were before, then perhaps it is not worth to age the closing votes (and a week worth means that all the votes are decayed).

Comment: @Asaf Why, I agree with your proposal entirely.

Comment: To the downvoters, I'd be interested in hearing your opinion as to why this is a bad feature request.

Comment: Am I right in saying the current system seems particularly well-suited to exploitation from those trying to delay the closure of a question? Should we flag a question for moderator attention if we see something like this happen?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, but the case that brought this "bug" or "exploit" to my attention was such that I don't think the OP was trying to delay or avoid having the question closed. Just to increase interest in the question. The bounty itself was placed in good faith, I believe. It's just the question itself... was mostly an attempt to affirm that the OP is correct, and argue anyone claiming otherwise (e.g. most of the given answers...)